# How to change node.js memory settings to allow very large (>100gb) memory

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, v8

I have a rather large json file containing several million geojson points. I'm able to read it in with JSONParser without a problem. I'm then attempting to process the file with [geojson-vt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-vt).

For the test file set I used that was 700mb this worked fine when I set the --max_old_space_size v8 parameter to 8gb or so. Now I'm trying to work with a 3gb full file for a single state and running into issues. It seems no matter how high I set the max_old_space_size parameter it will only use around 34gb before the garbage collector kills it on an allocation failure, even though I set max_old_space_size to 50gb.

I've read about some other v8 parameters that could potentially be used. Here is the last command I attempted to run:

```
node --max_executable_size=5000 --max_old_space_size=54000 --max-semi-space-size=5000 -nouse-idle-notification --noconcurrent_sweeping app.js
```

Here is the failure from that command.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[27445:0x2e900d0]   587348 ms: Scavenge 29492.1 (31038.4) -> 29422.8 (31521.9) MB, 2092.6 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[27445:0x2e900d0]   591039 ms: Scavenge 30244.6 (31803.4) -> 30175.9 (32273.4) MB, 2070.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[27445:0x2e900d0]   594706 ms: Scavenge 30972.9 (32544.4) -> 30904.8 (33028.4) MB, 2060.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[27445:0x2e900d0]   620992 ms: Scavenge 31727.0 (33311.4) -> 31656.7 (2783311.9) MB, 24589.5 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x12299bc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xa6b34b [node]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceAndCandidates() [node]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node]
 9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]
12: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
13: 0x1a296258ed46
Aborted
```

It seems like no matter what it won't grow past this limit. Are there other parameters I can set to allow it to grow more and GC less?

I realize this isn't the typical use case for node.js and it's probably not the best tool for the job, but if I can get geojson-vt to work then there's some other libraries that can make processing this data set much easier so I'd like to go this route if it's possible.

I have basically unlimited memory that can be used for this task; up to a few TBs, so that's not going to be a limiting factor. This dataset I'm using is actually a very small part of a larger one that will need to be processed so I'm going to have to scale beyond where I am now.

Environment details:

- Node.js is version 7
- Running on CentOS 7

Comment: Can you split big file to appropriate pieces and do buffered process?
Can you make stream parsing?
Probably something like that  could help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream

Comment: Unfortunately the section I'm working on is dependent on having all of the data available at once. It's trying to summarize tiles based on the points. I'm looking into modifying the library to see if there's anything to be gained there but for the time being it looks like I'm somewhat stuck. Splitting them up is an option as a last resort but makes it much harder down the road when I need to serve the summarized tiles to web clients.

Comment: if your algorithm can be buffered, you might want to try the stream approach

Comment: Probably your algorithm can be done with several passes, each one can scan all data, aggregate or process something and then output the data for next pass or/and iteration

Comment: I've had to do this with one library already, but that one was straight forward with how it could be optimized. Here is the one that's causing the issue this time: https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt/blob/master/src/index.js Specifically the geojsonvt(json, options) call.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

- Try setting only `--max_old_space_size`, no other flags. (The specific failure you're seeing has to do with newspace; I'm not surprised that a semi space size of several gigabytes is causing issues, as there's no reason to make it that big.)
- Try using a newer Node.js version (either 8.x, or even the `vee-eight-lkgr` branch on https://github.com/v8/node for the very latest state of development). There have been some recent fixes to better support super-sized heaps.

Comment: To be more specific: V8 5.8 introduces official support for arbitrarily large heaps, see: https://v8project.blogspot.com/2017/02/one-small-step-for-chrome-one-giant.html . So Node 7.x is just too old (it has V8 5.5 in it).

Comment: I believe it should be --max-old-space-size (with hyphens and not with underscores)

Comment: @sandiejat: V8's flags parser recognizes both hyphens and underscores and treats them exactly the same. You can use whichever you prefer.

Comment: You are correct. https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#options 
Easy to miss when you see all flags follow hyphenated convention :)